# "KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'". Sites.py broken in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, site-packages

I think this got foobarred when I was doing some brew update stuff. Everytime my system python3 is called, it emits:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:  
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

This is particularly annoying because I use powerline in my terminal and powerline makes several calls to python each time I execute a command.

Calling Python3 with a the Verbose flag I get:

```
$ PYTHONVERBOSE=True python3

<multiple pages of python startup info...>

# possible namespace for /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports
# bytecode is stale for 'sitecustomize'
# code object from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 481, in execsitecustomize
    import sitecustomize
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py", line 15, in <module>
    str(sys.version_info[0]) + '.x!\n     PYTHONPATH is currently: "' + str(os.environ['PYTHONPATH']) + '"\n' +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
# destroy sitecustomize
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x101e3a630>

<more python startup info...>
```

So the system Python3 is trying to load the Python2 version of sitecustomize? I suspect that's the problem. If so, what are my options for fixing this? `brew unlink python3 && brew link python3` didn't help.

I'm not sure what the `bytecode is stale for 'sitecustomize'` comment python is making is about, but I've also removed the sitecustomize.pyc file, which didn't help.

Comment: One interesting problem here is that you appear to be using Python 3.6 but it's importing 2.7's sitecustomize file.  What does `env | grep PY` show?

Comment: Not much: PYTHONSTARTUP=/Users/liavkoren/.pythonstartup
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=true. I added dontwritebytecode years ago, and my .pythonstartup only has a shortcut for `from datetime import datetime` and `from pprint import pprint`.

Comment: What is in .pythonstartup?  What's craze here is that it's looking in very much the wrong location for sitecustomize... so it seems like a path is off somewhere.  Like the location is being added through some mechanism (such as your .pythonstartup) or PYTHONPATH is being set directly (though I doubt this is the problem because of the KeyError you are seeing).

Comment: There's nothing relevant in my .pythonstartup. : )

Comment: I agree, it seems the problem is py3 trying to load a py2 sites.py. I don't know why that's happening, tho, or what good options to fix are. Should I just delete and install or do I need to track down a python path problem or..?

Comment: I noticed that calling python with -s ("Don’t add the user site-packages directory to sys.path") prevents the KeyError. Exporting  PYTHONNOUSERSITE in my bashrc file prevents the messages from being printed, although the shell prompt is still *noticably* slower than if was before this issue appeared.

Comment: I don't think re-installing will help you.  I suspect there's something else in your file system/environment/customizations that is being picked up that's causing the issue.  I think the trick is tracking that down.  Have you tried exporting PYTHONVERBOSE=2 (instead of True)?  It'll show a little more about what is happening and might help you see where things are going sideways.  I'd pay close attention to the python start up info.

Comment: It looks like it's search *many many* paths for python3 sitecustomize.py file before it finally tries the python2 version. Here's a gist with a longer, verbosity=2 sample: https://gist.github.com/liavkoren/0de6d0d48b840ee61a184c8181f45670

Comment: AFAICT, nothing is setting my PYTHONPATH. If I do an `echo $PYTHONPATH` in the shell, nothing is printed, and adding `unset PYTHONPATH` to .bashrc doesn't change anything.

Comment: Wow... it looks to be heading to Python 2.7's stuff pretty early on.  Alright, two more questions: do you have any .pth files anywhere?  And, what does `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` show?

Comment: Result of both of those are in: https://gist.github.com/liavkoren/a430ca37a5f7ca62e8eb2dd6d257ed77

Comment: Just be be sure, I uninstalled pdbpp, which is the package that adds "_pdbpp_path_hack" to pythonpath. No change.